# Login bug on Stack Overflow

Tags: bug, login

I am unable to log in on Stack Overflow. I mean the "log in with Facebook", "login with Google+" and "login" button freeze (aren't clickable) on clicking.

Can somebody please help?

Comment: Is this specific to SO? It seems like you're not logged in here, either?

Comment: yeah it seems to be specific to SO as I was easily able to log in at meta stack exchange but not to SO and this problem is prevailing since a month or two.

Comment: is it the same account?  Logins are supposed to be persistent across all Stack Exchange sites, so if you manage to login into MSE, you should automatically be logged into all sites in which you have an account

Comment: What browser are you using?

Comment: chrome  55.0.2883.87 (64-bit)

Comment: When I switch from MSE to SO using the tab at the top of the page then there it shows a tab to login which means I am not logged in there and when I try to login there then the buttons freeze!!

Comment: If you have an account on either site, either this isn't it or you haven't got any content... because right now, this account is linked to nothing other than this question. Are you sure you didn't accidentally create a new account?

Comment: I faced the same problem when I tried to login using google+ even for the first time.BTW does it have anything to do with accounts coz I am just not able to click on any buttons!!

Comment: Do you have any extensions/add-ons/plugins? Try disabling them all and see what happens.

Comment: yeah I have the panda extension

Comment: Are you getting any errors in the developer console? Anything on the network? The login page should always be HTTPS - is that not the case?